# Given "PDO", what is the purpose of "mysqli_stmt"?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I'm reading up on **php db classes** and everything i'm reading recommends **"PDO"**. Cool. So what then is the *purpose* of **"mysqli_stmt"**? Is is deprecated?

Please advise.

sleeper.

Comment: possible duplicate of mydqli or PDO pros and cons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons

Comment: @yamikoWebs. Agreed. I searched, but maybe my search criteria wasn't specific enough.

Comment: `PDO` and `mysqli` both use a low-level library created for communication with MySQL. They basically use the same low level code, but they expose a different API to the programmer. Whether you use one or another, you are, in fact, calling the same code essentially. `PDO` is, in my opinion, much easier to use and as stated in the answers, with `PDO` you have the same API that can *speak* multiple RDBMS "languages", keeping the API the same. The purpose in using `mysqli` would be that you prefer `mysqli` for some reason (or you have a legacy app that's been developed with `mysqli`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to do things.  PDO is a database layer that allows you to use many different database types via various drivers.  `mysqli_*` is only for MySQL.

Both will get the job done when using a MySQL database.  I recommend PDO, but that is just my preference, as I like the flexability of possibly changing databases more easily in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Mysqli is said to be the faster performance wise of the two, however the features of PDO far outweigh those of Mysqli in my opinion. I also prefer the flexibility of PDO when changing databases.

Answer (score 2):

`PDO` is an abstraction layer, `mysqli` is an extension that interacts directly with the database.